# Including a native SDK (for IOS and Android) into flutter

Tags: swift, flutter, kotlin, sdk

i am currently facing the following problem and I hope someone can help me out:

I want to write an app in Flutter (yes I already compared this framework to others like React Native and Ionic) but i need to include the motiontag SDK and here is where the problem starts.
The Motion Tag SDK is only available for native App descreptive native programming language (Java/Kotlin, Swift).

Is there a way to include the SDK anyway to flutter??
Like some workaround!

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter does have communication with native via [Platform Channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels), so if the sdk is just function calls you could call the function from flutter/dart , and then let the platform channel handle the call to the native function with arguments. If the sdk it's about rendering UI inside flutter then it's more complicated but it's possible as long as you use the boundaries of [PlatformView](https://itnext.io/using-native-ui-in-flutter-with-platformview-6b9d46265332) . All the native plugins developed for flutter use this two methods to handle native code/UI

Comment: Thank you very mich!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer from MotionTag. The question is from 3 years ago, but we do have a flutter plugin;

https://github.com/MOTIONTAG/motiontag-sdk-flutter